# Is it possible to make this HTML/JavaScript list display more than two digits?

Tags: javascript, html

This script is inside of an HTML code and works fine but when applied to an ordered list it begins with "00" and ends at "99" and repeats instead of going endlessly until the list is finished:

```js
function search_animal() {
  let input = document.getElementById('searchbar').value
  input = input.toLowerCase();
  let links = document.querySelectorAll('#list li');

  links.forEach((e) => {
    e.classList.toggle("active", e.innerText.toLowerCase().includes(input))
  });
}

let searchbar = document.querySelector("#searchbar");
searchbar.addEventListener("input", search_animal);
```

```html
<input id='searchbar'>
<ol id='list'>
  <div class="animals">
    <li><a target="_blank" href="example.com">Example</a></li>
    <li><a target="_blank" href="example.com">Example</a></li>
    <li><a target="_blank" href="example.com">Example</a></li>
    <!-- this repeats forever, this is an example -->
  </div>
</ol>`
```

I have tweaked the code in various different ways without severely effecting anything but the output was always the same. It starts at '00' then ends with '99' and repeats instead of including a 3rd or 4th digit. I don't really know what else to change now.

Comment: I don't see the numbers. It might help to make a [working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: You can see it here: https://linkd1.github.io/linkd1/unbloc.html . It's a site for people at my school to use and I want to improve the shown search bar

Comment: The hundreds digit are there, just not visible. You can shift the list items to the right, for example `li.active {margin-left:15px}` or `#list {padding-left :58px}`. Also note that the li elements should be directly within the ol, and the ol should not directly contain a div. Currently you have ol > div.animals > div.column > li

Comment: checked the link. in devtools I see your `li` elements have a `display: none` on them (defined in the `style` tag in the head of your document). once i removed that i could see up to number 415 :)

Answer (score 0):

The padding just needed to be increased to 58px or above because the     `<div>` element had an absolute size which prohibited the text from showing completely.